# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, ssh

First:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Connecting to SSH servers gives this message:

```
$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8m 25 Feb 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/charlie/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/charlie/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/charlie/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/charlie/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

My /etc/hosts.allow is as following:

```
sshd: ALLOW
```

/etc/hosts.deny is as following:

```
ALL: ALL: DENY
```

I have changed my /etc/ssh/sshd_conf as following:

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key


RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 6):

Double check the perms on your `.ssh` dir and your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  Those need to be `chmod 700` and `600` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure

```
sshd: ALLOW
```

is invalid syntax for hosts.allow.  You probably mean ALL, not ALLOW.

Answer (score 2):

You can get "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" if your `sshd` service is not operational!

If you have access to the server check you have the `sshd` service running with:

```
  ps aux | grep ssh
```

and check it is listening on port 22:

```
 netstat -plant | grep :22
```

[more details here](http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-check-if-ssh-is-running-on-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message. I was trying to ssh from MacOS X 10.6.3 to Ubuntu Server 9.04.

I found out that denyhosts on Ubuntu would forcibly insert the following into by /etc/hosts.deny:

```
sshd: nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn
```

Even when deleting this entry and restarting denyhosts, this line would return.

In order to fix this, I followed this [FAQ](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html#3_19) to remove my blocked IP address from the specified files in the WORKING_DIR (/var/lib/denyhosts in Ubuntu).

Mind you, as I write this, I am 20 minutes out of having resolved this as far as I can see - I shall advise if I experience a regression.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was solved by adding

```
sshd: ALL
```

to  /etc/hosts.allow

Answer (score 0):

Read your -vvv output again:

```
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/charlie/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
```

What's in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?

What do you get if you run  `telnet localhost 22`?